# php header location not redirected from 404

Tags: php, mysql

Hi friends i have one problem with my redirect page php section.

This is my php redirect section:

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['uid']) && $_SESSION['uid'] != '')) {
header('Location: '.$base_url.'index.php');
exit;
}
include_once 'includes.php' ;
    if($_GET['user_name']){
        $user_name=$_GET['user_name'];
        include_once 'public.php';
        }
      if(empty($_GET['user_name'])) {
        header(location:$url404);
}?>
```

`$url404"` is in `includes.php`

`$url404=$base_url.'404.php';`

The problem is page not redirect if username empty

Comment: is this line `header(location:$url404);` syntaxically correct ?
I'm not sure

Comment: First thing I can see is `header(location:$url404);` should likely be `header("Location: " . $url404);`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `"`, so it's not seeing the header as a string.

Change `header(location:$url404);` to `header("Location:" . $url404);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if(!isset($_GET['user_name']) or $_GET['user_name'] == "") {
        header("location:".$url404);
```

Hopefully this will help you.